# My nextJs app is loading each page while navigating

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a pretty huge NextJs app, whenever I run `yarn run dev` the app is working on 3000 but whenever I click on navigate/page, each page is refreshing, like Jquery, and also my NodeJs is consuming close to 3GB of ram, so basically when I navigate my page compiling taking toooo long, I have 8GB of ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, during development, the code is not efficiently built, and on each navigation, if the page for the URL you are visiting (*if not visited earlier*), Nextjs will create that page at runtime `with hot-relaod` and that is why you may see that delay.

---

**How you can test this?**

- Have an error in one page & a page is completely fine with no errors.
- Go on the first page which is fine and has no error, that page is loaded perfectly, but when you go on the second page's URL you will see the error.

> This implies that on running `npm run dev`, each page is built individually and one page is only created once it is required.

---

> On the other hand, `npm run build` creates an efficiently built bundle all the pages in the `build` folder at once. And above example will not be built and will show some error.

You can read more about this on https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15053#discussioncomment-143243